# utf 8 character not showing on android

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts

I've made a web app that relies on some utf-8 characters rendered in `<pre>` tags. The app also stores text files locally the SD card of the android device and meant to be viewed later in a text viewer app (any).

The characters appear as intended everywhere (mac, pc, iphone) but on Android phones. These superscript characters (7⁴  7⁶  7⁷  7⁹  7⁺) don't display in text files (when loaded from the SD card) or in web browsers.

How can I fix this or use a similar character to accomplish the job? The most important thing is to have two numbers side-by-side (7⁷) but look visually different, that don't require any markup, but will look different in plain text as well.

Comment: I'm reading your question from Android, and I'm currently seeing all your characters.

Comment: `don't display in text files`. Of course not. You cannot display text in a file. You store text in a file. If you want to see the text you have to display it on a screen. It is pretty unclear how you try to display your text.